# (PHP) Imagick-created gif animation: setting the frame disposal?

Tags: php, animation, gif, imagick

I would like every frame to be drawn anew, without the frame before it drawn behind it. My current code is:

```
// $frames is an array of image blobs
$durations = array(50, 50, 50, 50)
$loops = 0;

$big = new Imagick();
$big->setFormat('gif');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($frames); $i++) {
    $frames[$i]->scaleImage(140, 140);
    $frames[$i]->setImagePage(140, 140, 0, 0);
    $frames[$i]->setImageDispose(1);
    $big->addImage($frames[$i]);
    $big->setImageDelay($durations[$i]);
}
$big = $big->deconstructImages();
$big->setImageIterations($loops);
$big->writeImages('test.gif');
```

None of the `setImageDispose()` settings achieve what I want:

1. `setImageDispose(1)`: [example image](http://puu.sh/heCv8/68c1e7985f.gif)
2. `setImageDispose(2-3)`: [example image](http://puu.sh/heCvz/1e6864fb1c.gif)

Though (1) appears to work as intended, it is still drawing the previous frames underneath. How can I simply set it to Gimp's equivalent of "replace", where each frame is drawn independantly? Is there another function I have not found that would solve this?

Thank you.

**Additional notes:**

- I have tried using `setImageDispose()` on both the frame object and the
  eventual gif object and both have the same outcome (above)
- I have tried `setImagePage()` to no avail, but perhaps I was using it wrong?
- When my $frames are echoed individually they each are drawn complete.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. `deconstructImages()` was optimizing the frames in the way we see in the `setImageDispose(2-3)` example above. My solution was to have a toggle for these tweo functions, so I can either output as:

- `setImageDispose(1)` - larger filesize but no overlapping frames
- `setImageDispose(2); deconstructImages()` - smaller filesize

Depending on the animation I am building, I can dispose or not. My final code is something like this:

```
// $frames is an array of image blobs
$durations = array(50, 50, 50, 50)
$loops = 0;
$dispose = false;
```

---

```
$dispose_mode = ($dispose) ? 2 : 1;

$big = new Imagick();
$big->setFormat('gif');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($frames); $i++) {
    $frames[$i]->setImageDispose($dispose_mode);
    $frames[$i]->scaleImage(140, 140);
    $big->addImage($frames[$i]);
    $big->setImageDelay($durations[$i]);
}
$big->setImageIterations($loops);
$big = ($dispose) ? $big : $big->deconstructImages();
$big->writeImages('output.gif', true);
```